# Prolog planner only generates one plan

Tags: prolog, artificial-intelligence, planning

I have a prolog planner which works correctly with one major problem of only generating one plan at the time. The plan is correct but for my application I really need to have all the possible plans.

```
plan(State, Goal, _, Moves) :-  subsetB(Goal,State),
                            write('moves are'), nl,
                            reverse_print_stack(Moves).
plan(State, Goal, Been_list, Moves) :-
                            effects(Name, [Preconditions, Add,Delete]),  //a list of of rules governing the domain
                            conditions_met(Preconditions, State),       //checks if all preconditions are present in the state
                            change_state(State, Add,Delete, Child_state), //add predicates from Add list, removes predicates in the Delete list and stores result in Child_state
                            \+(member_state(Child_state, Been_list)),     //checks if Child_state hasn't been previously visited
                            stack(Child_state, Been_list, New_been_list),
                            stack(Name, Moves, New_moves),
                    plan(Child_state, Goal, New_been_list, New_moves).


change_state(S, [],[], S).
change_state(S, [], Delete, S_new) :-   change_state(S, [],[], S2),
                                    apply_del(Delete, S2, S_new).
change_state(S, Add,Delete, S_new) :-   change_state(S, [], Delete, S2),
                                    apply_add(Add, S2, S_new).


apply_add([],State,State).
apply_add([activate(App)|Rest],State,InterimState) :-apply_add(Rest,State,S2),find_stones(App,State,StonesToBeActivated), make_active(StonesToBeActivated,S2, InterimState).
apply_add([First|Rest],State,InterimState) :- apply_add(Rest,State,S2),add_element(First, S2, InterimState).


apply_del([],InterimState,InterimState).
apply_del([First|Rest],InterimState,NewState) :- apply_del(Rest, InterimState,S2),del_element(First, S2, NewState).



subsetB([],_).
subsetB([F|R],S) :- member(F,S),subsetB(R,S).



%dropping a stone inside app1 
 effects(drop(X,app1),                     %action
   [[stone(X),active(X)],                  %preconditions
    [in(app1,X)],                          %postconditions : add list
    [active(X)]]).                         %postconditions : delete list

go(S,G,AllPlans):- findall(Moves, plan(S,G,[S],Moves),AllMoves).

conditions_met(P, S) :- subsetB(P, S).
```

Sample call
   go([in(app1,s1), stone(s2), active(s2),stone(s3),active(s3)],[in(app1,s1),in(app1,s3),in(app1,s2)],AllPlans).

Answer:

drop(s2,app1)
drop(s3,app1)        //correct
_2368
_2366
_2364
_2362
_2360
_2358
_2356
_2354
_2352
_2350
_2348
_2346
_2344
_2342
_2340
_2338
_2336
etc... infinitely

Comment: Your code line starting with `apply_add([activate(App)|Rest],State,InterimState)` truncates prematurely with a `$`. Copy paste error?

Comment: It is really difficult to follow the logic of your program, but the problem seems to be that your end-of-recursion is not defined properly.... Moves is not instantiated at the beginning, but seems to be part of the solution, too....

Comment: I thought that's how I get sicstus to actually return the variable?

Comment: Well yes, but it is alone in the first call up there -- where is it coming from? If you remove the side effect (the printing out) you will immediately get a "singleton variable" error. And I still cannot run your code because I am missing some definitions in the code you have here : right now it is `conditions_met`

Comment: added, it's just subsetB (added for clarity, when I copy that bit into my report)

Comment: :( add_element, del_element are part of the sets library, and make_active and find_stones are not used in the short example. in fact all of the second definition for apply_add isn't used, and is not the reason only one plan is produced.

Comment: I think this is the complete code: http://pastebin.com/XNvyZRKE Sorry for the mess of a question.

Comment: I have a sneaking suspicion that there is a much _much_ simpler way of solving your actual problem... can you describe what it is that you are trying to do, really? I can almost make sense of the first answer (the one that you get) but it is not enough to guess.

Comment: I have a bunch of rules about the world, with action, preconditions, affects added to new state, effects removed from old state. I'm trying to print out a list of actions which gets me from the start state to the end state. at the moment, with the old version of go which just calls plan, I get one single correct plan. Conditions_met checks the preconditions are met, if so, change state is applied and I make sure I achieve a new state (to avoid looping) I then add the new state to the list of states I've already been and push the action onto the stack of actions taken so far.

Comment: See my yet another edit...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For finding all solutions to a goal, look at [bagof or findall](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%274.30%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/allsolutions.html%27%29%29). Or am I missing something?

Like this:

```
?- findall(Moves, plan(State, Goal, _, Moves), AllMoves).
```

The whole idea of these predicates is that you say which arguments you want to collect and get a list of all possible instantiations under that predicate. In this sense you normally have a "return" value (an argument that gets instantiated with the result) that you can then look at or print, instead of printing it explicitly in the predicate that finds solutions.

A simplistic example:

```
foo(1). foo(2). foo(3). foo(4). foo(5). foo(6).
bar(R) :- foo(A), A mod 2 =:= 0.

findall(R, bar(R), Even).
```

Now to recursion: how does it work? You cannot share variables between different clauses of the same predicate. For example, this is wrong:

```
baz(0, B).
baz(X, B) :- X0 is X - 1, B1 is B + 1, baz(X0, B1).
```

because B is a singleton variable in the first clause of `baz`. Instead, you can do:

```
baz(0, B, B).
baz(X, B, Result) :- X0 is X - 1, B1 is B + 1, baz(X0, B1, Result).
```

which you can now call:

```
?- baz(10, 2, Result).
Result = 12
```

but you will still run into problems after the first answer.

You get the single correct plan *probably* because the first clause of `plan` does not meet the requirements of `subsetB`, and you get to the second clause. There, you make a *Moves* that has a free variable at its Tail, but this is not a problem yet. The problem is, however, that when you find your first solution (all in the second `plan` clause, recursively), *Moves* is now bound to a list of actions, and instead of starting to look for a new solution, you get into the second clause again **by backtracking**, with the already filled in *Moves*, which probably messes up the rest of the algorithm.

To make it correct, you probably need to make sure that when your `plan` backtracks, it starts to look for a new solution, with a clean *Moves*. You can start by instantiating *Moves* to an empty list and collecting results in an accumulator, as shown in the simplistic `baz` predicate above.

Comment: As in findall(Moves, (contents of plan(_,_,_,_), Allplans).?

Comment: @Nieszka You need to say explicitly which arguments you want to collect (see my edit).

Comment: That will work as long as the predicate indeed finds multiple solutions. It wasn't clear from the problem description whether it only could find one solution, or whether he failed to press the right key to see additional solutions. Definitely worth a shot.

Comment: It keeps coming up with the same plan infinitely :(

Comment: @Nieszka There is a problem with your code, but without an example invocation it is difficult to find the error: I don't even know how to call your `plan`... Edit the question with an example call and output!

Comment: Done! Had to do plan(State,Goal,[State],Moves) because otherwise it loops infinitely

Comment: Oh, I mean, I added the sample call and output, it produces an infite sequence and only one plan :(